# How to compare a range of cells with a table column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks with sheets  1 & 2. I want to compare the header names of workbook1 sheet A (i.e. Range A1:BZ1) with the names in workbook2 sheet B column A.

I have tried copying the data into an array and then tried finding the heading files in the table column

```
Sub Multi_Find()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim fullpath
Dim temp As Variant

Dim xyz As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

    'It's a good idea to still check if the file type selected is accurate.
    'Quit the procedure if the user didn't select the type of file we need.
    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Open the file selected by the user
    Workbooks.Open fullpath 

Set wb2 = Workbooks("DBSteuerungsdatei.xlsm")
'Workbooks opened from microsoft explorer
Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(fullpath)


temp = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:BZ1")

wb2.Activate

    Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LookUp").ListObjects("Table1")
'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set Temparray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(Temparray)

'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)

   xyz = temp.Find(what:=myArray(fndList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False)
  Next x


End Sub
```

- if nothing is missing than the program should terminate
- if a missing header from workbook 1 is found it should open an input box which allows user to enter correct names in column 1 and column 2 of the table

Comment: I am still looking forward for someone to answer this question

Comment: The issue with this question probably is that the question you ask ("How to …") is too broad to answer, and there is no specific proplem that you have with your code just 2 requirements in the end of your question. • So could you narrow it down to a *specific* point? What works already in your code and where *exactly* does it fail (what does it do vs. what did you expect) or did you get any errors? Please read [mcve]. Also example data and screenshots how it looks before and what you expect after would help. Note [tag:macros] tag is not an appropiate tag for VBA questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code

I made sure that the files are selected using the windows dialog box
After selection, the header files were checked against the first column of the table and the new data was replaced from the second column

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
' This program checks the headers in sheets and update
' them according to the new header values from the Table

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim fullpath


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show
        
        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    
    'It's a good idea to still check if the file type selected is accurate.
    'Quit the procedure if the user didn't select the type of file we need.
    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
    'Open the file selected by the user
    Workbooks.Open fullpath


 
Set wb2 = Workbooks("DBdata.xlsm")
'Workbooks opened from microsoft explorer
Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(fullpath)
wb2.Activate

'Create variable to point to your table
    Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LookUp").ListObjects("Table1")
'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set Temparray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(Temparray)
'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
    
   wb1.Activate

    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
      For Each sht In wb1.Worksheets
        If sht.name <> tbl.Parent.name Then
          
          sht.Cells.Replace what:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
                 
        End If
      Next sht
  Next x
  
MsgBox ("The changes in " & wb1.name & " are done!")
wb1.Close savechanges:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```